# Flash AI - Can enemies learn "zones" or "areas"

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, artificial-intelligence

Playing around with artificial intelligence. Was wondering if enemies can learn what areas to randomly wander around in, based off of certain variables.

For example, can an enemy learn what areas are "safe" and "dangerous" based off of how many other enemies have died in certain areas? And then can the enemy learn to only wander around in the "safe" zone?

Comment: Yes, your enemies can learn anything you want them to if you have the data available. Tracking zones and enemy deaths wouldn't be too hard.  Your question though is much too broad for stack overflow.  Try something, and if you run into problems, post the code you're trying and explain what is or isn't happening and the desired outcome

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Stats like favorite attacks, power-ups, and the like need to kept against the player. Setting a halo around the player (usually line of site) can trigger collisions with objects and rank them as favorite destinations for the player to head. Training a bot to chase the destination as to the player when the destination is closer makes it more difficult for the player to steal the prize. Having each attack combinations ranked so that the bot can study them against the player. When he learns what works, he can be trained to always approach that attack first. There are several methos for AI in all gaming environments that support collision detection.